# Bootstrap dropdown login form floating out of screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here I am trying a sample bootstrap form that has a login dropdown, for username and password, I am including the code below, when the login form is activated, the form floats out of the menu on the right side of the screen, The code is below:

```
<div class="navbar  navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="nav-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="brand" title="">
                Test
                </a>

      <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">

         <li>
           <form class="input-append" method="GET" action="/search" style="margin-top:4px;margin-bottom:5px;">
             <input type="text" title="Enter keyword(s) to find" id="TT" name="TT" class="span2" maxlength="40">
               <button type="submit" class="bton">
                 <i class="icon-search" title="Search"></i>
               </button>
           </form>&nbsp;&nbsp;
         </li>



        <li class="dropdown" id="menuLogin">

                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" id="navLogin">Login</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" style="padding:17px;">
                                <form id="formLogin" class="form"> 
                                    <label>Login</label> 

                                    <input name="username" id="username" type="text" placeholder="Username" pattern="^[a-z,A-Z,0-9,_]{6,15}$" data-valid-min="6" title="Enter your username" required="">
                                    <input name="password" id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" title="Enter your password" required=""><br>
                                    <button type="button" id="btnLogin" class="btn">Login</button>
                                </form>
                                <form><a href="#" title="Fast and free sign up!" id="btnNewUser" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#formRegister">New User? Sign-up..</a></form>
                                <form id="formRegister" class="form collapse">

                                    <input name="email" id="inputEmail" type="email" placeholder="Email" required="">
                                <input name="username" id="inputUsername" type="text" placeholder="Username" pattern="^[a-z,A-Z,0-9,_]{6,15}$" data-valid-min="6" title="Choose a username" required=""><br>
                                <input name="password" id="inputpassword" type="password" placeholder="Password" required=""> 
                                <input name="verify" id="inputVerify" type="password" placeholder="Password (again)" required=""><br>                                  
                                <button type="button" id="btnRegister" class="btn">Sign Up</button>
                            </form>

                        </div>

                    </li>


    </ul>
```

What is the problem in the dropdown, I tried a nav pull-left in the dropdown, 
 but it did not work, thanks.

Comment: please can you provide jsfiddle

Comment: bootsnipp link: http://bootsnipp.com/user/snippets/2pRy0

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the bug, the line reading:

```
 <div class="dropdown-menu" style="padding:17px;">
```

should have a dropdown-menu-right added so the correct line should be:

```
  <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" style="padding:17px;">
```

The "dropdown-menu-right" wraps the menu correctly!